# Can logistic regression, Neural Network and SVM give the same accuracy when using the same training/test set? If so, why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, logistic-regression

I used the three algorithm with the same training and test set. However I'm getting the same exact mean accuracy for all of them. Is there any good explanation on why this is the case for me. I read it may have something to do with the classes being used might be considered easy.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a bit weird that this happens but I have to make assumptions regarding to your question:

1. The MLP architecture consists of a `n` inputs and one hidden neuron and `m` outputs.
2. You use a linear kernel for the SVM
3. Your test and training data is linearly separateable.

If 1. is true, your network is equal to logistic regression and your data is separate by a line which leads to the 3. and also to 2. because you won’t need a kernel function to separate the data.

So, the weird part is, that the SVM turns the computation of a decision boundary of your classifier into a convex optimization problem to solve for the optimal boundary. Neither Logistic Regression nor an MLP is able to do this. Hence, your **test** data must be really easy to separate and must lay with a larger margin to the decision boundary than your training data. This way, it’s not necessary to have a optimal margin between the classes and any boundary which separates the classes without error is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: I have only one predictor. This is the Neural network  code I'm using banknet <- neuralnet(as.numeric(bank$loan)~bank$age, bank_train,
                       hidden=2, lifesign="minimal",
                       linear.output=FALSE, threshold=0.1).                            And yes I'm using linear kernel for this. I notice there was a relationship between the age and loan when doing the conditional plot

Comment: See my attached pic to visually understand the reason.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

They can all give identical performance if your problem is simple enough. There's nothing stopping them from giving you identical results.

Comment: Sorry, if accidentally tapped the wrong vote. If you update your answer, I’ll upvote it.